# Issue adding MongoDB Java Driver as a Maven dependency

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, intellij-idea

The title says it all really, my pom is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>CouncillorsApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The following error is given:

"Dependency 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:3.10.2' not found"

I'm using Java 14.0.2 and the latest version of IntelliJ

Comment: Does it build from the command line using `mvn clean package`? What error do you see there? Is there any proxy configuration required for your system?

Comment: What does `mvn dependency:tree`say about this?

Comment: Given the pom that you've shared, there is no mention of `org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync` and its not a transitive dependency of the [artifact `mongo-java-driver`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.12.6/jar) either. Also, this doesn't quite relate to the Java version, so editing the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after restarting IntelliJ the above code seems to work fine. I'm unsure of where the issue was, but the dependency is being found now without any changes to the pom.

Answer (score 1):

please [read installation](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.12/driver/getting-started/installation/#mongodb-driver-sync)

you can try this

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

On the right side of the IDEA, click `Maven`

[image]

Click `blue circled button`.

[image]

Then dependencies should throw no more errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on VPN for different environments, please make sure it is connected to the environment of your data. This happened with me.